# Check if indexing operator exists

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I want to be able to:

- Check if an object has an indexing operator defined.
- If it is defined, I want to be able to use it.

I want to implement this in the following code.
The code contains an object (MyObject) that offers a way to traverse through a multidimensional array or linked set of hash tables. Also it should prevent giving errors if a node in the requested path doesn't exist.
The part that I can't figure out is the commented part in the code:

```
public class MyObject
{
    private object myObject = null;

    public MyObject()
    {
    }

    public MyObject(object value)
    {
        myObject = value;
    }

    public void setValue(object value)
    {
        myObject = value;
    }

    public object getValue()
    {
        return myObject;
    }

    public object this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (myObject == null) 
            {
                return new MyObject(null);
            }
            else
            {
                // determine what of type/class myObject is and if it has indexing operators defined
                // if defined, access them and return the result
                // else return null.
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if (myObject == null)
            {
                // do nothing (or throw an exception);
            }
            else{
                // determine what of type/class myObject is
                // determine if that type/class has indexing operators defined
                // if defined, access them and set the result there
                // else do nothing (or throw an exception).
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I wish to accomplish:

```
        // given these variables:
        string loremIpsumString = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
        int[] digits = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) digits[i] = i;
        Hashtable outerHashtable = new Hashtable();
        Hashtable innerHashtable = new Hashtable();
        innerHashtable.Add("contents", "this is inside");
        outerHashtable.Add("outside", "this is outside");
        outerHashtable.Add("inside", innerHashtable);

        // I can already print this:
        Response.Write(    loremIpsumString    ); // prints "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
        Response.Write(    digits[0]    ); // prints "0"
        Response.Write(    digits[1]    ); // prints "1"
        Response.Write(    digits[2]    ); // prints "2"
        Response.Write(    outerHashtable["outside"]    ); // prints "this is outside"
        Response.Write(    ((Hashtable)outerHashtable["inside"])["contents"]    ); // prints "this is outside"

        // But I want to be to do it this way:
        MyObject myObject;

        myObject = new MyObject(loremIpsumString);
        Response.Write(    myObject.getValue()    ); // prints "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
        Response.Write(    myObject["unexistant"].getValue()    ); // prints nothing/null
        myObject = new MyObject(digits);
        Response.Write(    myObject[0].getValue()    ); // prints "0"
        Response.Write(    myObject[1].getValue()    ); // prints "1"
        Response.Write(    myObject[2].getValue()    ); // prints "2"
        myObject = new MyObject(outerHashtable);
        Response.Write(    myObject["outside"].getValue()    ); // prints "this is outside"
        Response.Write(    myObject["inside"]["contents"].getValue()    ); // prints "this is inside"
        Response.Write(    myObject["unexistant"].getValue()    ); // prints nothing/null
        Response.Write(    myObject["unexistant"]["unexistant"]["unexistant"].getValue()    ); // prints nothing/null
```

Comment: Ok, I see that now. Sorry I didn't follow the first few reads through

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can first check if it's inheriting `IList` to cover (generic) `Lists` and Arrays. If not you can  use [`PropertyInfo.GetIndexParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getindexparameters.aspx) to check if it has an indexer instead:

```
get
{
    if (myObject == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        // not sure which index(es) you want
        int index = 0;
        Type t = myObject.GetType();
        if (typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(t))
        {
            IList ilist = (IList)myObject;
            return ilist[index];
        }
        else
        {
            var indexer = t.GetProperties()
                .Where(p => p.GetIndexParameters().Length != 0)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            if (indexer != null)
            {
                object[] indexArgs = { index };
                return indexer.GetValue(myObject, indexArgs);
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/M7rvBr) (with a `string` which has an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars.aspx) to access the chars)

Comment: @nl-x: And you need a `using System.Linq;`!.

Comment: @nl-x: Linq is normally better redable. But use whatever you can/want to use. The query is not the essential part of my answer. It's `GetIndexParameters().Length`  and `indexer.GetValue`.

Comment: @nl-x: Edited my answer to provide an aproach which also works with arrays and lists since both inherit from `IList`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter : though your solutions actually helpful to my problem, it seems to not be really an answer to the question; being How to know if an indexing operator exists, and how to use them. Surely there must be a way to find out if an object/class has indexing operators (square brackets []) set? Why need an if-array-iList-else-GetIndexParameters solution? (I will mark your answer as accepted though)

Comment: @nl-x: An array/list does not have/use an indexer to access the values. An indexer just uses a similar syntax as an array but actually it's aproperty. That's why all collection's `GetIndexParameters.Length` is 0. It's very easy and efficient to access an array/list's values without reflection as i've shown above. That's why i've checked first if it's castable to `ILIst` which is the base interface of all collections(even generic).

Answer (score 1):

You can test if the object is a dictionary

```
public object this[string key]
{
    get
    {
        var dict = myObject as IDictionary;
        if (dict == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (dict.Contains(key)) {
            return dict[key];
        }
        return null;
    }
    set
    {
        var dict = myObject as IDictionary;
        if (dict != null) {
            dict[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Note: If you have the control over the dictionary type to use, then prefer `Dictionary<string,object>` over `Hashtable`. Its handy method `TryGetValue` allows you to safely access it without first calling `Contains` and thus saves you from accessing it twice. Of cause you would then cast to `Dictionary<string,object>` instead of `IDictionary`.

```
var dict = myObject as Dictionary<string,object>;
if (dict == null) {
    return null;
}
object result;
dict.TryGetValue(key, out result); // Automatically sets result to null
                                   // if an item with this key was not found.
return result;
```

Comment: I tried going into this path before, but failed miserably. I'll try again!

Answer (score 0):

For others looking for the answer. Here is what I made of it with @TimSchmelter 's help.

So this is the code that I implemented in the get{} that I used in the code at the top of this screen, where in the top of this screen the get{} just contained comments.

```
get
{
    if (myObject == null)
        return new MyObject(null);
    object returnValue = null;
    bool foundReturnValue = false;
    object[] indexArgs = { key };
    Type myObjectType = myObject.GetType();
    if (typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(myObjectType))
    {
        try
        {
            returnValue = ((IList)myObject)[((int)key)];
            foundReturnValue = true;
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
    if (!foundReturnValue)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in myObjectType.GetProperties())
        {
            ParameterInfo[] indexParameters = property.GetIndexParameters();
            foreach (ParameterInfo indexParameter in indexParameters)
            {
                if (indexParameter.ParameterType.IsAssignableFrom(key.GetType()))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        returnValue = property.GetValue(myObject, indexArgs);
                        foundReturnValue = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception) { }
                }
                if (foundReturnValue == true)
                    break;
            }
            if (foundReturnValue == true)
                break;
        }
    }
    return new MyObject(returnValue);
}
```